Serilog App Insights Correlating Logs via OperationId Azure Functions
I have manage to get my function app logging to Azure via serilog but its not correlating / grouping the logs correctly. I have tried using an encricher like so:
public class OperationIdEnrichment : ILogEventEnricher
{
    public void Enrich(LogEvent logEvent, ILogEventPropertyFactory propertyFactory)
    {
        logEvent.AddOrUpdateProperty(new LogEventProperty("OperationId", new ScalarValue(Guid.NewGuid())));
        logEvent.AddOrUpdateProperty(new LogEventProperty("ParentId", new ScalarValue(Guid.NewGuid())));
    }
}

Created a telemery converter
public class OperationTelemetryConverter : TraceTelemetryConverter
{
    private const string OperationId = "OperationId";
    private const string ParentId = "ParentId";

    public override IEnumerable<ITelemetry> Convert(LogEvent logEvent, IFormatProvider formatProvider)
    {
        foreach (var telemetry in base.Convert(logEvent, formatProvider))
        {
            if (TryGetScalarProperty(logEvent, OperationId, out var operationId))
            {
                telemetry.Context.Operation.Id = operationId.ToString();
            }

            if (TryGetScalarProperty(logEvent, ParentId, out var parentId))
            {
                telemetry.Context.Operation.ParentId = parentId.ToString();
            }

            yield return telemetry;
        }
    }

    private bool TryGetScalarProperty(LogEvent logEvent, string propertyName, out object value)
    {
        var hasScalarValue = logEvent.Properties.TryGetValue(propertyName, out var someValue) && (someValue is ScalarValue);
            
        value = hasScalarValue ? ((ScalarValue)someValue).Value : default;

        return hasScalarValue;
    }
}

Hook this up using
var config = TelemetryConfiguration.Active;
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
     .MinimumLevel.Information()
     .Enrich.FromLogContext()
     .Enrich.With<OperationIdEnrichment>()
     .Enrich.WithExceptionDetails()
     .WriteTo.ApplicationInsights(config, new OperationTelemetryConverter(), LogEventLevel.Information)
     .CreateLogger();

var host = new HostBuilder()
    .UseSerilog()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
    .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
    {
        services.AddLogging(x => x.AddSerilog());        
    })
    .Build();

host.Run();


Is there something I am missing here?

ParentId should be a valid OperationId correct? But you just invent ParentId in your Enricher so there is no Operation with that Id.

They should be the same value?

I don't know what you want to achive its your code. I can just assume ApplicationInsights expects hierarchical Ids. The stuff almost everywhere is used and not just a random bunch of chars like a Guid. You might want to take a dive into the Activity class that tracks those.

Managed to figure this out. I got rid of the enrichers and the telemetry converter so my packages now look like
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.22.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.1.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http.AspNetCore" Version="1.2.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.ServiceBus" Version="5.13.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.17.2" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights" Version="2.22.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Exceptions" Version="8.4.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Extensions.Hosting" Version="8.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights" Version="4.0.0" />

Hooking this up is simplified
var config = TelemetryConfiguration.Active;
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
        .MinimumLevel.Information()
        .Enrich.FromLogContext()
    .WriteTo.ApplicationInsights(config, TelemetryConverter.Traces, LogEventLevel.Information)
    .CreateLogger();

var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWebApplication()
    .ConfigureServices(x =>
    {
        x.AddLogging(y => y.AddSerilog());
    })
    .UseSerilog()
    .Build();

host.Run();

Result is, my use of logger.Log() is being attached to the underlying operation. I am not setting it myself which is what I wanted to avoid doing.

